# THREAD 1 SIGABRT error

Tags: xcode

I just started with Xcode programming and I encountered my first problem when I run my app without any extra codes, methods, properties or classes. I started with the template SINGLE VIEW and I changed the .xib to MainWindow and added an object called basically App Delegate. I removed the single view object from the MainWindow.xib and replaced it with a UIWindow.

I receive the following classic THREAD 1 SIGABRT error:

```
App[4178:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "ViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x14f8022 0xef8cd6 0x14a0a48 0x14a09b9 0x1222dd 0x122779 0x12299b 0x81401 0x81670 0x81836 0x8872a 0x1ff5 0x59386 0x5a274 0x69183 0x69c38 0x5d634 0x13e2ef5 0x14cc195 0x1430ff2 0x142f8da 0x142ed84 0x142ec9b 0x59c65 0x5b626 0x1d2d 0x1c95 0x1)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

I already reviewed existing postings, but I could not get wiser on it.

Comment: Your view controller needs to have some kind of UIView attached to its `view` property in the .xib file in order to load properly.  The things you say you did don't actually make a lot of sense to me but, in the end, the error is about not having a view connected.

Comment: Thanksamillion! I figured it out. It's all about linking. So I run and everything builds. But right after that it shows an error about the rootviewcontroller, that it needs to be specified at the end of the appication launch. Then I connected the rootviewcontroller from UIWindow to the File's Owner... Now it builds like it does before but it doesn't show anything. It is just pitch black. Can anybody help me with some pointers to look for the problem?

Answer (score 2):

It seems very confusing, but is actually very simple. The Thread1: SIGABRT glitch means that something is interrupting your connections.

This may be caused by declaring your connection as weak, and declaring it as strong in your code. In order to tell what you declared your connection by clicking on the object that is having the problem, and then going to the connections inspector (the symbol with a circled arrow). This will let you see the connection.

Now try changing your code declaration from strong to weak (or the other way around), then running your program. If this does not work try deleting the code of the entity, and deleting the connection by hovering over it in the connections inspector and clicking the "X" that shows up.

After deleting the connection, and code try reconnecting the entity and the code should reinstall by itself.